# Finding probability that randomly chosen observation of binary variable is equal to 1

Tags: r, probability, estimation

I have a dataset consisting of roughly 200.000 respondants. It contains, among other variables, the educational level of the respondant and his/her parents. For every respondant who reports to have the same educational level, compared to his/her parents, the binarycolumn takes `educ_pers == 1` and if educational levels are different `educ_pers == 0`.

What I would like to do is capture the probability that a **randomly chosen respondant** of this cohort has the same educational level of his/her parents i.e. `educ_pers == 1`. If possible, additional confidence intervals would be great.

When I simply calculate the mean and the corresponding t-statistic of educ_pers the confidence intervall is unreasonably large, as binary values cannot distribute closely around the mean.

PS: Any concrete help in would be appreciated in R-language!

Comment: I would take as an estimate of the probability of having a match to one's parent as 'p', the sample proportion with sampling variance given here https://www.statisticshowto.com/finite-population-correction-factor/ .

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, the probability that a randomly selected observation has the same educational level as his/her parent is simply the proportion.

In R you can find the confidence intervals for this proportion using prop.test. Let's say that 50,000 out of 200,000 have the same educational level.

```
prop.test(x = 50000, n = 200000)
```

Of course, with a sample of this size, the confidence interval is very tight but as AJKOER points out above, if your sample of 200,000 includes more than ~5 percent of the entire cohort (population), you can use the finite population correction, to adjust your confidence interval so that it's even tighter.